# Active class using *ngIf

Tags: typescript, angular6

```
 <li (click)="leftMenuEvent(lMenu)"  *ngFor="let lMenu of leftMenuDetails" [ngClass]="{active: setleftActive(lMenu)}">
          <a><img alt="" [src]="lMenu.normalimg">{{lMenu.text}}</a></li>
```

My thing is to change the `[src]` to `lMenu.selectedimg` on `[ngClass]={active}`
(i.e):When on clicked

Comment: you want it to change on clicking the anchor tag right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li
  (click)="leftMenuEvent(lMenu)"
  *ngFor="let lMenu of leftMenuDetails"
  [ngClass]="{ active: setleftActive(lMenu) }"
>
  <a><img alt="" [src]="setleftActive(lMenu) ? lMenu.selectedimg : lMenu.normalimg" />{{ lMenu.text }}</a>
</li>
```

Did you mean this?

Comment: Glad to know that, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Apply `ngClass` this way.

```
[ngClass]="{'active':setleftActive(lMenu)}"
```

**Update**

To update the [src] value :

```
[src]="flag ? lMenu.selectedimg : lMenu.normalimg"
```

When you clicked on

just make flag true on it's click event.

In .ts file

```
flag: any = false; // Dafault it will false. 


leftMenuEvent(event){
     this.flag = true;
}
```

**Note:** Either you can use `setleftActive(lMenu)` instead of falg. Both are same.

Comment: No thats not my need,it is when i click my <li> i want to change the <a> [src]="lMenu.normalimg" to [src]="lMenu.selectedimg"

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
getImage(menu: lMenu) {

if (active) {
    return (menu.selectedimg);
  } else {
    return (menu.normalimg);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
 <a><img alt="" [src]="getImage(lMenu)">{{lMenu.text}}</a>
```